# wordpress coinslider not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm developing my customing wordpress theme and I want to create a featured content slider on the homepage so I installed the coinslider wordpress plugin, but there's no featured post. I'm quiet new to wordpress development so forgive my ignorance if the answer is obvious. I included the functions.php and my header.php is well linked to jquery. Why is this not working people? Please help

Comment: your wordpress version is what ? if you use this plugin  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/coin-slider-4-wp/  This plugin hasn't been updated in over 2 years. It may no longer be maintained or supported and may have compatibility issues when used with more recent versions of WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

Did you know that by default, Wordpress loads jQuery with noConflict?

Basically, you're stuck with 2 options:

**jQuery:**

```
jQUery(document).ready(function(){
    // code using jQuery.fn
});
```

**or (function($))(jQuery):**

```
(function($){
    // code using $.fn
})(jQuery);
```